# Recognition of nipple exposure in the image, and Automatically cover nipple area

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I'd like to implement something like the title, but I wonder if it's technically possible.

I know that it is possible to recognize pictures with CNN,
but I don't know if can be automatically covered nipple area.

If have library information about any related information,

I would like to get some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNNs are able to detect whatever you train them for, to varying degree of accuracy. What you would need are a lot of training samples (ie. samples of ground truths with the original image, and the labeled image) with which to train your models, and then some new data which you can test the accuracy of your model on. The point is, CNNs are not biased to innately learn a task, you have to tell them what to learn!

I can recommend the machine learning library Keras (https://keras.io/) if you plan to do some machine learning using CNNs, as it's pretty simple and somewhat beginner-friendly. Take some of the tutorials for CNNs, which are quite good.

Essentially, you have what I can only assume is a pretty niche problem. The main issue will come down to how much data you have to train your model. CNNs need a lot of training data, especially for a problem like this which isn't simple. A way which would make this simpler would be to have a model which detects the *ahem* area of interest and denotes it as such on a **per-pixel** basis. Then a simple mask could be applied to the source image to censor it. This relates to *image segmentation*, and there are many academic papers on the topic.